# Auto tag link creation while saving the wordpress post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

*Hello I am using wordpress 6.3.2 version and generatepress theme.*

**I have searched for plugins which can create a tag links automatically while saveing /publishing/updating the posts. But they are creating dynamic links while user access the post for reading. But I want link to be created and saved in db (hard coded links for tag keywords). I have asked chatgpt for code that is given below code but its creating hard links for tags but Post is not getting saved.**

> here is the code. can anybody suggest whats the issue with this php function?

````
    // Check if the post is being saved or updated.
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return;

    // Get the post object
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    if ($post) {
        // Retrieve all tags
        $tags = get_tags();
        $content = $post->post_content;

        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            $tag_name = $tag->name;
            $tag_link = get_tag_link($tag->term_id);
            $tag_link_html = '<a href="' . $tag_link . '">' . $tag_name . '</a>';
            $content = str_replace($tag_name, $tag_link_html, $content);
        }

        // Update the post content with tag links
        wp_update_post(array(
            'ID' => $post_id,
            'post_content' => $content,
        ));
    }
}

add_action('save_post', 'auto_link_tags_on_publish');```
````